# Android parentActivityName with TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack stopped working on API 21 (Lollipop)

Tags: android

I'm using this code to setup back stack navigation when opening the app from a widget.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ComposeActivity.class);

// Create an Intent to launch ComposeActivity

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ComposeActivity.class);

// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button

RemoteViews recordButtonImageView = new RemoteViews(
  context.getPackageName(), R.layout.record_widget
);

recordButtonImageView.setOnClickPendingIntent(
  R.id.record_button, pendingIntent
);
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml definition

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.ComposeActivity"
            android:label="@string/compose_activity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MyFeedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">

        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MyFeedActivity"/>

</activity>
```

it's working great for API 14 - 20 but not for API 21.

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  The chosen answer doesn't seem to address the problem, and we are using 22.2.0 and still seeing the issue on Lollipop.

Comment: same problem with 23.0.0. I am testing on android TV (OS 5.1.1) and it is not working. Even tried to replace the CATEGORY_LAUNCHER with CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER and no results. Task back stack seems to be created ok with 2 intents, but back action is not working. Did not find any android bug on this, have you logged one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently came across this very same issue.

This seems to be a bug in `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+`. Using the recently released version 22 it's working once again, even though the change is not mentioned in the cangelog.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem. and when I changed the `requestCode` param in method `getPendingIntent`, problem solved. It seems that `requestCode` must be greater than 0. 
so you can change

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

to

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

Comment: YES! You saved my life and a number of big important contracts with this little snippet. Your cheque is in the mail, sir!