# OnBackPressed and onOptionsItemSelected not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-xml

I have one activity that will simply call the previous activity once onBackPressed was called or the onOptionsItemSelected. My code is working on Kitkat, Ice cream, and Marshmallow. It is only not working in **Lollipop**. Why is that?

My Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

}
```

Android Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ReminderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_reminder_activity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activities.MainActivity" />

    </activity>
```

build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "quality.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pointwest.timetrackermobilelog"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 36
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.2'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
    }

  }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.+"
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:0.6.3'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.3'


}
```

Comment: where is your code where you return the the previous activity in onOptionsItemSelected()? I mean, onBackPressed it´s clear, that goes automatically, but on select item, there must be some finish() call or liek I see in Manifest some `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);`  call

Comment: what happens on `lollipop`? `logcat`?

Comment: Do not override   onBackPressed() {

Comment: @Haroon....why not `override onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs already used `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` still not working.

Comment: I don´t think it´s a lollipop problem, I think it´s a manufacturers android implementation problem. Which device you are testing?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I already tested with Asus, Samsung, and Sony Xperia. All of them are Lollipop. All of them didn't work. However, I also used Google Nexus, Samsung Kitkat, and Samsung Ice cream. All of these work.

Comment: ok, what happens on lollipop if you press back button? does it quit or is just nothing happen?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs It closes the app.

Comment: it seems to be a bug on the API. Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421347/android-parentactivityname-with-taskstackbuilder-addparentstack-stopped-working

Comment: according to the link it seemed that the `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+` seemed to have a bug. ill check it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

`onOptionsItemSelected` is a method which is recalled when you are going to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.